# XML XSLT Transformation in XE7 FireMonkey (iOS)

Tags: xml, delphi, xslt, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

Been spinning my wheels for days now...

Does anyone know how to do an XML/XSLT transform in Delphi XE7 FireMonkey (for iPad/iOS)?

I know my XML and XSL files are working, as a test I have added the XSL stylesheet tag to my XML file and dropped it into IE to test (from my Windwos7 machine), ended up with exactly what I needed (a well formatted HTML page).

This is what I've done:
1) Drop a TXMLTransform (from the XML section of palette) onto my Mobile form
2) Created following routine:

```
procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.LoadHtml( AXML: String; 
                                                AXSL: String );
begin
  try
    // Transform XML and place HTML into our WebBrowser
    XMLTransform1.SourceXmlFile := AXML;
    XMLTransform1.TransformationFile := AXSL;
    FWebBrowser.LoadFromStrings( XMLTransform1.Data, '' {ABaseURL} );
  except
    on E: Exception do
      DisplayHtmlError( E.Message, AXMLFileName );
  end;
end;
```

I also tried to insert the style sheet tag within the XML file and just load the XML into IE, did not work.

The XML and XSL files both have encoding="UTF-8", but for some reason, it only works in Windows.

Is there a recommended way to do this? 
Is there a specific library I should be using for iOS?

Please do not point me to any Windows library/links, I need this to work on iOS (an iPad) using FireMonkey XE7.

Please pardon my ignorance and thank you in advance,
Richard

Comment: Do your XML and XLS files have UTF-8 BOM? If not, try adding it.

Comment: Thanks Dalija, yes both files have UTF-8 BOM. Didn't make a difference under iOS/FireMonkey.

Comment: Which XML DOM are you using?

Comment: The XML file was created using OXML (from Kluug.net), I believe it is based of OMNIXML, I don't mind using something else, just want it to work/compile under FireMonkey/iOS.

Comment: I meant which DOM you use in Delphi under iOS for loading files. It looks like you are facing either some configuration issue or bug...